# the navbar collapses but the hamburger icon doesn't display the menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is the tribute page project for fCC, so the problem is that the navbar collapses and all but the hamburger icon doesn't display the menu, and `data-spy="affix"` isn't working either please help.
This is the codepen page: https://codepen.io/HatimShady/full/Nyxaqm/

```
<nav data-spy="affix"  class=" navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsemenu">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#intro">Tribute: Alan Turing</a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapsemenu" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-right navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#synopsis">Synopsis</a></li>
            <li><a href="#early-life">Early Life</a></li>
            <li><a href="#caec">Cryptanalysis and Early Computers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#death">Death</a></li>
            <li><a href="#rec">Awards, Recognition and Royal Pardon</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: For starters you haven't included Bootstrap JS in the Codepen.

Comment: @ZimSystem I just did, thank you. But it's still not working

Comment: Bootstrap's JavaScript also requires jQuery, you need to add that too.

Comment: @MirzaSisic thank you for replying, yes I just did that too, nothing's changed